# How to solve warning: Unchecked call to 'addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<? super TResult>)

Tags: android, warnings, raw-types

I get the next warning from AndroidStudio `Unchecked call to 'addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<? super TResult>)' as a member of raw type 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task'`

I am trying to remove it, recognize that I have to declare the Listener with a type, but when I try to make

```
t.addOnSuccessListener<byte[]> (new ...
```

it does not even compile.

```
Task t = ImageController.getProfilePicture( mContact );
                t.addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>( ) {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess( final byte[] bytes ) {
                        mProfilePicture.setImageBitmap( PictureConversion.byteArrayToBitmap( bytes ) );
                    }
                } );
```

This last one is the code from my listener and the implementatin of getProfilePicture is the next one:

```
public static Task getProfilePicture( String userID ) {
    StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance( ).getReference( );
    StorageReference downloadRef = reference
            .child( DataBasePath.IMAGE.getValue( ) )
            .child( userID )
            .child( DataBasePath.PROFILE_PICTURE.getValue( ) );

    return downloadRef.getBytes( Long.MAX_VALUE ).addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>( ) {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess( byte[] bytes ) {
            byteArray = bytes;
        }
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a type to the Task, in your case, in the first line:

```
Task<byte[]> t = ImageController.getProfilePicture( mContact );
```